# SQL Select In List from Other Table

Tags: sql, select

I have TABLE1 and TABLE2 and I wish to create TABLE3 which selects row in TABLE1 ONLY IF the CLASS also appear in TABLE2.

This is my try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE CLASS IN (TABLE2.CLASS)

TABLE1
WEEK    CLASS   STUDENT
1   A   1
1   A   2
1   B   3
1   B   4
2   A   5
2   A   6
2   C   7
2   C   8
3   A   9
3   C   10
3   B   11
3   B   12
4   B   13
4   D   14
4   D   15
4   A   16


TABLE2
    CLASS   STUDENT
    A   1
    A   2
    A   3
    A   4
    F   5
    F   6
    F   7
    F   8
    F   9
    F   10
    F   11
    F   12
    F   13
    C   14
    C   15
    C   16
    C   17
    D   18
    D   19



TABLE3
WEEK    CLASS   STUDENT
1   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   5
2   A   6
2   C   7
2   C   8
3   A   9
3   C   10
4   D   14
4   D   15
4   A   16
```

Comment: That should work, does it not?  You can check out INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not valid, `in()` requires either a defined list of values or an *expression*, *TABLE2.CLASS*, in isolation, is niether (it should be `IN(SELECT CLASS FROM TABLE2)`)

You should however use *exists*:

```
select Week, Class, Student
from Table1 t1
where exists (
  select * from Table2 t2
  where t2.Class = t1.Class
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use in, exists or join to get your desired result.
just consider if you are using joins between tables you need to use distinct to avoid duplicated records.

```
Select t1.[Week], t1.[Class], t1.[Student]
From Table1  as t1 
Where Class in ( Select Class from Table2 )
```

or

```
Select t1.[Week], t1.[Class], t1.[Student]
From Table1  as t1 
Where exists( Select Class from Table2 t2 where t1.Class = t2.Class )
```

or

```
Select distinct t1.[Week], t1.[Class], t1.[Student]
From Table1 as t1 
inner join Table2 as t2 on t1.Class = t2.Class
```